# How to use .load to .prepend content without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery to only load certain content if the viewport is above a specified width.

This works, but not quite right. Check out the JsFiddle link at the bottom for a working demo.

*Here's what I have so far;*

- If the viewport is below 500px  **#wrapper** is hidden with a `media query`.
- Above 500px  **#wrapper** is set to `visibility: visible;`
- jQuery is looking for `element.is(':visible')`. When this happens jQuery loads the image.
- Resizing the browser window activates the `media query`, but not the `jQuery`.
- The `jQuery` only fires on a page refresh.

I've tried using `$( window ).resize(function()` but this fires *every time* the viewport changes size, duplicating the content.

**Is there a way to activate `jQuery` without a page refresh?**

*The ideal solution would be;*

- up to 500px load nothing,
- when the viewport is resized above 500px load the jQuery.
- If the viewport is resized below 500px unload the jQuery content.

**HTML**

```
 <p>CSS hides <strong>#wrapper</strong> if viewport is below 500 pixels.</p>
 <div id="wrapper">
<p>jQuery checks CSS to see if <strong>#wrapper</strong> is visible and loads image on page refresh.</p>
<p>I'm looking for a way to run this function without needing to refresh the page. I've looked into using (resize) function, but this duplicate the content.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
visibility: none;
display: none;
  }

   @media only screen and (min-width: 500px){
   #wrapper {
          visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        }}
```

**JQuery**

```
  $(function() {

 var element = $(this).find('#wrapper');

 if (element.is(':visible')) {
$('#wrapper').prepend('<img src="http://cache.desktopnexus.com/thumbseg/1134/1134934-bigthumbnail.jpg" alt="Demo image">');
  }
```

JsFiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/tu60wbbu/13/

Comment: Use `$( window ).resize(function()` and set a token. As long as the token is set, do nothing until the window size is smaller than 500px, then remove the token again.

Comment: Any chance you could give a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.matchMedia()` instead of `$(window).resize()` to have your javascript respond to a media query match in your CSS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

It's fairly well supported across browsers.
http://caniuse.com/#search=matchmedia

If you need to support IE 9 or lower, you might have to fall back to using `$(window).resize()` for those browsers.

Comment: That's neat for newer browsers. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for my comment:

```
$(function() {
var large = false;
var barrier = 1000;

$( window ).resize(function() {
    if(!large && $(window).width() > barrier) {
        large = true;
        $('#wrapper').prepend('<img src="http://cache.desktopnexus.com/thumbseg/1134/1134934-bigthumbnail.jpg" alt="Demo image">');
    } else if(large && $(window).width() < barrier) {
        large = false;
        $('#wrapper img').remove();
    }
}); 

});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tu60wbbu/14/
I used 1000px as the barrier in the demo.

You should initialize `large` properly by the window width on load. For demo purposes i used `false` as initial value.

*Sorry for the long time, I was at vaccation :-)*